# Nothing happens when compiling to the device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have a error/warning free application, that runs fine on the simulator. But when trying to compile to the device, even that I got a "Building succeed" and a "Finished running app with no issues" message, nothing happens on the device.

Note that:

- I have the latest Xcode version (4.2)
- My phone's Software version is up to date (4.2.1 on a iPhone 3G)

Anybody has some advice?

Comment: Restart your device and development machine. This happens sometimes to me.

Comment: I had this problem with an old iPod too after installed the new Xcode, the only way I found to build to the iPod was to use an older version of Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

Check that armv6 is included in the architectures you are building for.  Recent versions of Xcode silently remove this, which affects first and second generation iPod touches and the original iPhone and iPhone 3G.

Comment: I believe I had a similar problem and this answer fixed it for me.  Here was my question and answer on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7782763/how-do-i-use-the-ios-4-2-base-sdk-using-xcode-4-2  It's the same answer that my comment is attached to here.

Comment: @Jim, I'm not sure where to check this, but i guess i have it for armv6 as well. This screen shot shows it:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/12/screenshot20111129at114.png/
Where it says "Valid Architectures" is set to armv6 and armv7.

Comment: @MichaelWildermuth in the link you posted, some guy says Storyboards are not supported by iOS prior to 5.0. I am using storyborads. Could this be the reason? Do storyboards really don't work on iPhone 3??? Sounds weird...

Comment: No, storyboards are only supported by iOS 5 onwards.  There's nothing weird about new features only working on new models, it's the rule rather than the exception.

Comment: Also, if you look at your build settings, you will see that you only have armv7 selected.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't select the valid provisioning profile for your project. Select a valid one and it will work perfectly

Comment: I guess i did select the provisioning file. It's the first time I do this, so maybe I'm wrong. This image shows what my Organizer displays. I guess the provisioning file is correct:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/827/screenshot20111129at113.png/

Comment: Did you set it in Project settings? (Refer to the screenshot) http://gyazo.com/eb05c41b382b68eb0770561fb62f865f

Comment: No @d.lebedev , it wasen't properly set. It is now fixed and still don't work. It didn't seem to help...